# What argument max_instances means in APSchedulers

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have the following code:

```
import usbtmc
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler        

instr = usbtmc.Instrument(0x0699, 0x03a6)

print instr.ask("*IDN?")

sched = BlockingScheduler()

def TrigFreq():
  print instr.ask("TRIG:MAI:FREQ?")

sched.add_job( TrigFreq, 'interval', seconds=3, max_instances=10 )
sched.start()
```

i.e. I want to call the function `TrigFreq` 10 times with interval of 3 sec. But it never stops. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of `apscheduler` are you using?

Comment: I installed it by ``pip install apscheduler``. And it seems like 3.3.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your trigger, using `interval` will run forever. The max_instances only tells you how many concurrent jobs you can have.

APScheduler has three types of triggers:

`date
interval
cron`

interval and cron repeat forever, date is a one-shot on a given date.
If you want a trigger that triggers 10 times and then stops, then you would write a custom trigger based off either `SimpleTrigger` or `IntervalTrigger`, which keeps track of a counter so that it will stop triggering after the count runs out.

See https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one argument in order to stop the job on specified date and time. So pass the argument i.e `end_date` like this.

```
import usbtmc
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler        

instr = usbtmc.Instrument(0x0699, 0x03a6)

print instr.ask("*IDN?")

sched = BlockingScheduler()

def TrigFreq():
  print instr.ask("TRIG:MAI:FREQ?")

sched.add_job( TrigFreq, 'interval', seconds=3, max_instances=10, end_date='2014-06-15 11:00:00')

sched.start()
```

Source: [From Apscheduler 3.6 documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#examples)